# R filter in dataframe by columns

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, subset

I have a question about the following dataframe:

```
genes <- matrix(c("chr1","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr2",
              "uc001upw.2","uc001upw.2","uc001upw.2","uc001upx.1","uc001upy.1","uc001upz.1",
              "188001308","188001308","188001308","188037202","188037202","188037202",
              "188021266","188021266","188021266","188086618","188127464","188127464",
              "-","-","-","-","-","-",
              "CARCRL","CALCRL","CALCRL","TFPI","TFPI","TFPI", 
              "uc001upx.1","uc00upy.1","uc001upz.1","uc001upw.2","uc001upw.2","uc001upw.2",
              "188037202","188037202","188037202","188001308","188001308","188001308",
              "188086618","188127464","188127464","188021266","188021266","188021266",
              "-","-","-","-","-","-",
              "TFPI","TFPI","TFPI","CALCRL","CALCRL","CALCRL",
              "35894","35894","35894","35894","35894","35894"), nrow=6)

colnames(genes)<- c("chr","names.x","start.x","stop.x","strand.x","alias.x","name.y","start.y","stop.y","strand.y", "alias.y", "distance_startsite")
genes<-as.data.frame(genes)
```

In the dataframe you could see that the first three rows are unique by names.x and names.y.
Row 4, 5 and 6 are not unique, they are only shown in the opposite way.
My question is: Is there a way to filter this?

Thanks you!
Samantha

Comment: please generalize this question so that it serves a greater population than n = 1, where n = you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest way to do this I am sure, but it gets the job done:

```
genes[!duplicated(t(apply(genes[,c('names.x','name.y')],1,sort))),]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I run the code, I create a dataframe with 4 rows. row 2 and 4 are the same:

Comment: chr  names.x  start.x   stop.x strand.x alias.x    name.y  start.y
1 chr1 uc001upw.2 188001308 188021266       -  CARCRL uc001upx.1 188037202
2 chr2 uc001upw.2 188001308 188021266       -  CALCRL  uc00upy.1 188037202
3 chr2 uc001upw.2 188001308 188021266       -  CALCRL uc001upz.1 188037202
5 chr2 uc001upy.1 188037202 188127464       -    TFPI uc001upw.2 188001308
stop.y strand.y alias.y distance_startsite
1 188086618        -    TFPI             35894
2 188127464        -    TFPI             35894
3 188127464        -    TFPI             35894
5 188021266        -  CALCRL             35894